# Batch Script to start specific set of service

Tags: batch-file, scripting

Batch Script Failure. Incorrect syntax. If services are not running then start them and while starting trigger an email.

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('
sc queryex state^= all ^| findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME: .*Sm" get state^| 
Find /v "RUNNING"')
do net start "%%b"
```

**[Edit]**

Can you let me know where am i going wrong...I am checking Inactive Services and starting them while starting i am generating an email alert. But its getting looped and returning n number of mails. I personally need to terminate the process...if the service is running then also i am getting an email..

```
setlocal

:loop
@for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('sc queryex state^=inactive ^| findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME:.*ASP"') do net start "%%b" && goto :mail 

:mail
set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="abc@gmail.com"
set To="abc@gmail.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="smtp.gmail.com"
set User="abc@gmail.com"
set Pass="1234567"


if "%~7" NEQ "" (
set From="%~1"
set To="%~2"
set Subject="%~3"
set Body="%~4"
set SMTPServer="%~5"
set User="%~6"
set Pass="%~7"
set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"

echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: is this the actual format of your script in the batch file? `('` is wrong should be `('sc queryex....)` Also, you are trying to `get state` in the same string after find, that won't work.

Comment: thanks Gerhard, do i need to remove get state. I need to know service state if it is running then do nothing but if it is stopped then start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all services and try to find if they are running or not, instead get you can get the `inactive` status directly from the query, and start it from there:

```
@for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('sc queryex state^=inactive ^| findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME:.*Sm"') do (
    net start "%%b"
)
```

Note the above uses the parenthesis purely for readability, but they are not needed, you can copy all in one line, as per below:

```
@for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('sc queryex state^=inactive ^| findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME:.*Sm"') do net start "%%b"
```